# How to sync files between Windows 8 and Android device?

Tags: windows-8, sync, android

I've tried Microsoft SyncToy and FreeFileSync but the first app does not work with devices (I cannot choose any folder on my phone to sync).
FreeFileSync has poor sync options.
Are there any alternatives ways to sync files and folder between both Windows 8 and Android device offline? I don't want to use Dropbox or OneDrive because I don't believe they are completely safe.

Comment: what phone are u using?

Comment: @Botmaster It's not significant what phone I'm using. I connect my phone as external drive (media transfer protocol) and I'm able to view files standard way through Windows explorer. I need an app which allowed me to sync folders between my device and computer.